# Using Rotativa to export HTML into PDF file in ASP.NET Core MVC 7

Tags: asp.net-core, pdf-generation, rotativa

I am using ASP.NET Core MVC 7 and I want to use Rotativa package to export HTML (i.e. Razor View) into PDF file.

I install the required package using the package manager console:
`Install-Package Rotativa.AspNetCore -Version 1.2.0`

then I using the following Action code:

```
public IActionResult SavePDF()
{
            return new ViewAsPdf("PDF")
            {
                FileName = "MyPdfFile.pdf"
            };
}
```

where PDF is the Razor View name and MyPdfFile.pdf is the PDF file name
but, I have the following error on the run time

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1')
   at System.ArgumentNullException.Throw(String paramName)
   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
   at Rotativa.AspNetCore.WkhtmlDriver.Convert(String wkhtmlPath, String switches, String html, String wkhtmlExe)
   at Rotativa.AspNetCore.WkhtmltopdfDriver.ConvertHtml(String wkhtmltopdfPath, String switches, String html)
   at Rotativa.AspNetCore.ViewAsPdf.CallTheDriver(ActionContext context)
   at Rotativa.AspNetCore.AsResultBase.BuildFile(ActionContext context)
   at Rotativa.AspNetCore.AsResultBase.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Any suggestions please, thank you

I have tried to use Rotativa package (Rotativa.AspNetCore) to generate PDF file from the Razor View (HTML) while I am using ASP.NET Core MVC , and it does not work with An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Be sure add the following code in Program.cs:

```
RotativaConfiguration.Setup(builder.Environment.WebRootPath, "Rotativa");
```

2.Be sure your project contains `wkhtmltoimage.exe` and `wkhtmltopdf.exe` files which exist in the following location:

[image]

If not, you could download from github:https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa.AspNetCore. They located in `Rotativa.AspNetCore/Rotativa.AspNetCore.Demo/wwwroot/Rotativa/`. Then put the two files to your project.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the owner of the Nuget package. I just released a new beta version that works with .Net 7.

Please try the beta: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa.AspNetCore/1.3.2-beta

Basic configuration done in Program.cs (.net 6 or 7, beta package):

```cs
app.UseRotativa();
```

Let me know if you have issues, thanks.

Comment: it works too !!! , but it still a beta version (although it specified for ASP.NET Core 6 and 7)

Comment: @WadIHijjawi yeah it is, but I'll soon bump it to regular, latest, version. It is explicitly targeted to .Net >= 6.